# Derivative of $(\sin^2(t))^t$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve for the derivative of $G(t) = (\sin^2(t))^t$. My approach is to use the substitutions $u = \sin^2(t)$ and $v = \sin(t)$ yielding the equations

$G(t) = u^t$ and 
$G'(t) = \ln u\cdot u^t\cdot u'$

where $u = v^2$ and $u'=2v\cdot v' = 2\sin t\cos t = \sin 2t$

Using this approach, I get the answer $\ln(\sin^2(t))(\sin^2t)^t\sin 2t$, which is different from the correct answer $2(\sin^2t)^t(\ln\sin t+t\cot t)$. I understand why this answer is correct using logarithmic differentiation.

Could someone explain why my initial (and usual) approach for solving derivatives using chain rule is wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\frac {d}{dt}u^t = \frac {d}{dt}e^{t\ln u} =  u^t(\ln u + \frac {t}{u}u')$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The substitution $u$ depends on $t$.**
And you don't have $\frac{d}{dt} u(t)^t = \ln(u(t)) \cdot u^t(t) \cdot u'(t)$, but $$\frac{d}{dt} u(t)^t = t \cdot u(t)^{t - 1} \cdot u'(t) + u(t)^t \log(u(t)).$$ This can be seen through logarithmic differentiation by considering $$\frac{d}{dx} \log(y(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}\log(f(x)^{x}) = \frac{d}{dx} (x \log(f(x)) = \log(f(x)) + \frac{x \cdot f(x)}{f'(x)}.$$
Now $\frac{d}{dx} \log(y(x)) = \frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}$. Solving for $y(x) = f(x)^x$ gives the desired result.

Alternatively, you can write $f(t)^t = e^{t \log(f(t))}$ and then use $\frac{d}{dx} e^{g(x)} = g'(x) e^{g(x)}$, yielding (analogously to above)
$$
\frac{d}{dt} f(t)^t
= \left( \log(f(t)) + \frac{t \cdot f(t)}{f'(t)} \right) f(t)^{t}.
$$

---

In your case we therefore get
\begin{align}
G'(t)
& = t \cdot (\sin^2(t))^{t - 1} \cdot 2 \sin(t) \cos(t)
+ (\sin^2(t))^{t} \cdot \log(\sin^2(t)) \\
& = 2t \cos(t) \sin^{2t - 1}(t) + \sin^{2t}(t) \cdot 2 \log(\sin(t)) \\
& = 2 \sin^{2t}(t) \left[t \cot(t) + \log(\sin(t)) \right].
\end{align}